# The HTML/CSS part for brackets

Tags: css, html

I am developing a cup system, and I would like to get some advice to the bracket-part. The desirable result should look something like this:

> [image: Brackets]

http://www.partyplanning101.com.php5-7.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/tornament_board.gif

I would like to build op the page using div's combined with CSS - and not tables. How should I make this most optimally? Do any of you have a sample of this?

I am only asking for help regarding the HTML/CSS part, nothing else.

Comment: @hskrijelj Did you try something?

Comment: You ought to re-think the labels for your rounds: when there are 2 teams left, that's the final game, not the semi-finals.

Comment: Edited my post to include a finished version, the code can be cleaned up a lot but it works

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seemed interesting so I started developing, have to get back to work now so this is how far I got. The basics are laid out for you so you can finish it from here I think, though I will probably finish it in my spare time too and come and post it later

http://jsfiddle.net/AcuPp/

Update:

Finished - http://jsfiddle.net/AcuPp/3/

**CSS**

```
#container { 
    width: 800px; 
    height: 600px; 
    float: left; 
}

section { 
    width: 130px; 
    height: 520px; 
    float: left;
}

section > div { 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 20px; 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    margin: 10px 0; 
    background: #73789F; 
    color: white; 
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
}

section > div:nth-child(2n) { 
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.connecter { 
    width: 30px; 
    height: 520px; 
    float: left; 
}

.line { 
    width: 30px; 
    height: 520px; 
    float: left; 
}

.connecter div { 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    border-left: none; 
    height: 50px; 
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 80px 0 0 1px;
}

.connecter div:first-child { 
    margin: 32px 0 0 1px; 
}

.line div { 
    border-top: 1px solid #000; 
    margin: 133px 0 0 1px; 
}

.line div:first-child { 
    margin-top: 55px; 
}

#quarterFinals > div { 
    margin-top: 91px; 
}

#quarterFinals > div:first-child { 
    margin-top: 37px; 
}

#conn2 div { 
    margin-top: 133px; 
    height: 133px;
}

#conn2 div:first-child { 
    margin-top: 57px; 
}

#line2 div { 
    margin-top: 270px; 
}

#line2 div:first-child { 
    margin-top: 125px; 
}
#semiFinals > div { 
    margin-top: 230px; 
}
#semiFinals > div:first-child { 
    margin-top: 105px; 
}
#conn3 div { 
    margin-top: 125px; 
    height: 270px;
}

#line3 div { 
    margin-top: 270px; 
}

#final > div { 
    margin-top: 250px; 
}
```

​

**HTML**

```
<article id="container">

<section>
    <div>Player 1</div>
    <div>Player 2</div>
    <div>Player 3</div>
    <div>Player 4</div>
    <div>Player 5</div>
    <div>Player 6</div>
    <div>Player 7</div>
    <div>Player 8</div>
</section>

<div class="connecter">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="line">
    <div>
    </div><div>
    </div><div>
    </div><div>
    </div>
</div>

<section id="quarterFinals">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</section>

<div class="connecter" id="conn2">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="line" id="line2">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<section id="semiFinals">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</section>

<div class="connecter" id="conn3">
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="line" id="line3">
    <div></div>
</div>

<section id="final">
    <div></div>
</section>

</article>

​
```

Comment: Wow, that's a simple but effective approach. Awesome.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for sharing this. This is exactly, what I was searching for. The brackets need to be flexible; the brackets are generated automatically by the number of teams, so the number of boxes and rounds/stages are not the same always. I might need to make some changes such as having constant height-values - but the changes are minimal. Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My full, working solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/t9feh/

I would prefer a solution with purely semantic markup that would be easy to read and amend with data that might trickle in later, like who wins each match.

So I started with a markup structure with  players nested in matches, and matches nested in rounds.

### HTML:

```
<div class="tournament">

    <div class="round quarter-finals">

        <div class="match" >
            <div class="player">Player 1</div>
            <div class="player winner">Player 2</div>
        </div>

        <div class="match">
            <div class="player winner">Player 3</div>
            <div class="player">Player 4</div>
        </div>    

        <div class="match">
            <div class="player">Player 5</div>
            <div class="player winner">Player 6</div>
        </div>

        <div class="match">
            <div class="player">Player 7</div>
            <div class="player">Player 8</div>
        </div>    

    </div>

    <div class="round semi-finals">

        <div class="match">
            <div class="player">Player 2</div>
            <div class="player winner">Player 3</div>
        </div>

        <div class="match">
            <div class="player">Player 6</div>
            <div class="player">Player 7</div>
        </div>    

    </div>

    <div class="round finals"> 

        <div class="match">
            <div class="player">Player 3</div>
            <div class="player"></div>
        </div>     

    </div>

    <div class="round"> 
        <div class="champion"> 
            <div class="player"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that a class for  "winner" can be added to any player, and it will be styled appropriately.

The main challenge then is doing the connectors. Semantic markup means no design hooks. This then requires BG images. I used data-urls (see the utility I used at [DataURL.net](http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker)) to place these on  "matches" elements.

### CSS:

```
.tournament{width:720px;}

.round{
       float:left;    
}

.player{
    font-family:arial;
    width:120px;   
    height:20px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#73789F;
    color:white;
}

.player.winner{background:green;}

.match{
    padding:5px 50px 5px 0px;
}

/*QUARTER-FINALS*/
.quarter-finals .match{
    height:100px;
    background:right top no-repeat url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAABkAQMAAAD+JvEYAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAAAFnRFWHRDcmVhdGlvbiBUaW1lADEwLzEwLzEyGAKeIwAAABx0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAQWRvYmUgRmlyZXdvcmtzIENTNAay06AAAAAnSURBVCiRY/gPBgcYhjoNBPZQ/v4hQjeAHD0I3IGXRgpXqsbXEKEB2yGL0P7iVKIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
}
.quarter-finals .player{

}
.quarter-finals .player:first-child{
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

/*SEMI-FINALS*/
.semi-finals .match{
    padding-top:30px;
    height:185px;
    background:right top no-repeat url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAC5AQMAAABQhv7pAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAAAFnRFWHRDcmVhdGlvbiBUaW1lADEwLzEwLzEyGAKeIwAAABx0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAQWRvYmUgRmlyZXdvcmtzIENTNAay06AAAAArSURBVDiNY/gPBgcYRumBpYHAHsrfP0oPKboBFHmDwB2jNAk0Un77PwxoAJbztvAUr3KAAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
}

.semi-finals .player:first-child{
    margin-bottom:70px;
}

/*FINALS*/
.finals .match{
    padding-top:85px;
    height:350px;
    background:top right no-repeat url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAFeAQMAAAD9sN5nAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAAAFnRFWHRDcmVhdGlvbiBUaW1lADEwLzEwLzEyGAKeIwAAABx0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAQWRvYmUgRmlyZXdvcmtzIENTNAay06AAAAA0SURBVEiJY/gPBgcYRulRepQmngYCeyh//yg9So/Sg45uAGXSQeCOUXqUHrI0Uj33fxjQAEJS8U50LMSKAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
}

.finals .player:first-child{
    margin-bottom:180px;

}
/* CHAMP*/
.champion{padding-top:200px;}
```

Comment: Interesting! I just tried it out, and it gives the desirable result. I see your point of building it in rounds -> matches -> players. I intend to do something similar. However, I don't see the reason of connecting the boxes by using BG. I know, that's what semantic markup is about no hooking design. But I can't see, why it's necessary with semantic markup here. Which problems should occur? Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @hskrijelj: It's not at all necessary. I just like to leave the markup uncluttered. You could use a combined approach: nesting the elements the way I did, but using some extra markup here and there to draw the connectors, but I think it would be harder to read, and I prefer keeping style info in the stylesheet. Just my preference.

Comment: ...though if you think about it, the connectors do have semantic value. Though if I really wanted the relationships encoded in the markup, perhaps I'd add ids to the matches (like `id="match-1d"`) and a data attribute to each match like `data-winner-plays-in="match-2b"`, then, I don't know, maybe  draw the lines with some unobtrussive javascript (but that might be kinda hard).

Comment: I agree with most of your premises. I would like to think of myself as a more conventional programmer/designer. I use CSS where it's possible instead of images, even though this might appear easier in some cases. I would never place style info in a HTML file (unless it's really necessary). I think that using javascript to generate connecters is a overkill, but I like the idea. It's challenging and therefore quite interesting. I might give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. Alter the below code according to your div position.

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    width:580px; 
    font-family:verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:40px auto;
 }
#container {
    width:580px; 
    font-family:verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
 }  
#container a {
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#f6f6ff;
 }
#container a:hover {
    color:#900;
    background-color:#f6f6ff;
 }
#no1 {
    width:190px;
    line-height:60px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:auto;
 }
#no1 a {
    height:60px;
 }
#line1 {
    font-size:0;
    width:1px;
    height:20px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    margin:auto;
 } 
#line2 {
    font-size:0;
    width:424px;
    height:1px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;    
    margin:auto;
 } 
#line3 {
    font-size:0;
    display:inline;
    width:1px;
    height:20px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-left:78px;
    float:left;
 }  
#line4,#line5,#line6 {
    font-size:0;
    display:inline;
    width:1px;
    height:20px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-left:140px;
    float:left;
 }
#no2 {
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid #000;
    clear:both;
    margin-left:35px;
    float:left;
 }
#no2 a,#no4 a,#no8 a {
    width:84px; 
    height:50px;
    padding-top:8px; 
 }  
#no3 {
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-left:58px;
    float:left;
 }
#no3 a,#no5 a,#no6 a,#no7 a,#no9 a {
    width:84px; 
    height:42px;
    padding-top:16px;  
 } 
#no4 {
    display:inline;  
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-left:53px;
    float:left;
 }  
#no5 {
    display:inline;   
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-left:55px;
    float:left;
 }  
#line7,#line13 {
    font-size:0;
    display:inline;
    width:1px;
    height:38px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-left:219px;
    float:left;
 } 
#line8,#line14 {
    font-size:0;
    display:inline;
    width:1px;
    height:38px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-left:281px;
    float:left;
 }  
#no6,#no8 {
    display:inline;  
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-left:107px;
    float:left;
 }
#line9,#line11,#line15,#line17 {
    font-size:0;
    display:inline;
    width:26px;
    height:1px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;    
    margin-top:29px;
    float:left;
 }  
#line10,#line12,#line16,#line18 {
    font-size:0;
    display:inline;
    width:1px;
    height:60px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
 } 
#line16,#line18 {
    height:30px;
 }
#no7,#no9 {
    display:inline; 
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-left:169px;
    float:left;
 } 
.clear {
    clear:both;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">

<div id="no1"><a href="">Managing Director</a></div>
<div id="line1"></div>
<div id="line2"></div>
<div id="line3"></div>
<div id="line4"></div>
<div id="line5"></div>
<div id="line6"></div>
<div id="no2"><a href="#">Sales &amp; Marketing Director</a></div>
<div id="no3"><a href="#">Production Director</a></div>
<div id="no4"><a href="#">Human Resources Director</a></div>
<div id="no5"><a href="#">Finance Director</a></div>
<div id="line7"></div>
<div id="line8"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="no6"><a href="#">Factory Manager</a></div>
<div id="line9"></div>
<div id="line10"></div>
<div id="no7"><a href="#">Management Accountant</a></div>
<div id="line11"></div>
<div id="line12"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="line13"></div>
<div id="line14"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="no8"><a href="#">Quality Control Manager</a></div>
<div id="line15"></div>
<div id="line16"></div>
<div id="no9"><a href="#">Financial Accountant</a></div>
<div id="line17"></div>
<div id="line18"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>​
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/ZRJRj/1/

Comment: Really really bad solution. A lot of meaningless markup, only for the sake of styling. Of course, the Web has seen much worse, so who am I to complain. But this is SO, and I had higher hopes for the advice presented here ;-)

Comment: This won't come in handy in my situation, becauase I need to keep it flexible. There are, as @amn points out, to much markup. However, thanks for sharing and for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at SVG ( http://www.w3schools.com/svg/default.asp ) or, alternatively, Canvas ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element )

I would go with SVG. You'll need to calculate end points for your connector lines with some JavaScript, which you will draw with SVG right in the browser, and abstract it all neatly away behind simple interface. Actually, JavaScript is what will glue your entire application together, SVG is just for drawing, and HTML and CSS will aid you in presenting other parts of it.

Alternatively, you can use SVG to display the entire finals line-up. You will then use JavaScript to manipulate its contents to display proper team titles and relationships.

It will be beautiful.

Comment: I haven't worked so much with HTML5 and all the advantages within HTML. I will keep SVG in mind (I just read a bit about it, and it seems interesting). Thanks.

Comment: SVG is not really connected to HTML5, Canvas is. If you visit the SVG link I gave, you will see how easy it may prove to be for your case. You can even display the whole thing using a single SVG document. Or you can keep your `DIV`s (or generate the HTML using XML and XSLT) and only use SVG elements for the connector lines. JavaScript will in all cases prove to be the glue.

Comment: You are right, it appears to be quite easy. Yet, I'm more of a traditional programmer/designer. I like to build all the parts using only divs. But I will, as said, keep this in mind. Thanks again!